# MSVC Alias Template Bug?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, language-lawyer

I'm in the midst of converting a library I had previously written for clang and gcc onto MSVC, and I ran into what I assume has to be a bug, but I'm not versed enough with the standard to say for sure.

The following code produces errors about undeclared identifiers and invalid default arguments:

```cpp
template <class T>
struct dummy_struct {};
template <class T>
using dummy_alias = dummy_struct<T>;

template <template <class> class Thing>
struct foo {
    template <template <class> class T = Thing>
    void bar() {}
};

int main() {
    foo<dummy_alias> fdsa;
    fdsa.bar();
}
```

```
error C3202: 'Thing': invalid default argument, expected a class template
note: see reference to class template instantiation 'foo<dummy_alias>' being compiled
error C2065: 'Thing': undeclared identifier
```

Here's a Compiler Explorer link for the above example: https://godbolt.org/z/e2SEpD

The root of the issue appears to be MSVC being uncomfortable with alias templates being used as template template parameters.

I assume this has to be a bug, but I figured I'd run it by those potentially more familiar with the standard before I submit a report.
Thanks in advance!

To clarify, this code compiles without issue on recent versions of gcc, clang, and icc.

Comment: It would be better to include the actual error messages in the question.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the error messages, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a strict reading of the Standard, the program is ill-formed, so gcc and clang are wrong not to print a diagnostic.

However, I suspect the intent was that this should work, so maybe a Standard Defect Report is in order.

[[temp.param]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.param#3) says

> A *type-parameter* whose identifier does not follow an ellipsis defines its *identifier* to be a *typedef-name* (if declared without `template`) or *template-name* (if declared with `template`) in the scope of the template declaration.

So a template template parameter like `Thing` is a *template-name*, which makes it valid to write a *simple-template-id* like `Thing<int>`.

But [[temp.arg.template]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.arg.template#1) says

> A *template-argument* for a template *template-parameter* shall be the name of a class template or an alias template, expressed as *id-expression*.

(Technically a default template argument is not syntactically a *template-argument*, since the [*template-parameter* syntax tree](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.param#1) doesn't use the non-terminal *template-argument* after the `=` token, instead using *type-id* and *id-expression* directly. However, [[temp.param]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.param#11) makes them related, since the *type-id* or *id-expression* could be parsed as a *template-argument*: "A default *template-argument* is a *template-argument* ([temp.arg]) specified after `=` in a *template-parameter*.")

Here `Thing` is certainly not the name of a class template, and nothing says it's the name of an alias template, just a *template-name*.

Comment: This is fascinating, @aschepler, thanks so much for the detailed breakdown here. I had a feeling this was likely to be extremely nuanced. I've never made a standard defect report, if you think it's justified, I'm certainly interested in doing so. Any kind of documentation you'd be able to point me toward for that?

Comment: If I understood correctly you are saying that by strict reading `Thing` is a *template-name* but does neither *name a class template* nor *name an alias template*? Wouldn't that cause many more issues where the standard talks about a *template-name* *referring to* or *naming* specific kinds of templates? msvc also doesn't seem to implement this particular reading, because it should then disallow `Thing` as *template-argument* everywhere, [but doesn't](https://godbolt.org/z/3EEkkc).

Comment: @uneven_mark Well, the only ways to have a _template-name_ are the actual _id-expression_ from a template declaration, which is the name of a class template, function template, variable template, or alias template; or, a template _template-parameter_. True, MSVC is clearly not going by this reading. It seems it just happens to fail on the one case.